# How to enable publishing in crafter 3.0

Tags: crafter-cms

We recently get a lot of messages in crafter 3.0 tomcat log saying:

> Publishing is disabled for site xxxx

I was wondering how to enable back this site.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

This document will help you determine why your deployer is stopping.
http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/studio/debugging-publishing-issues.html

Once you have that figured out you can restart it via the API:
http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/projects/studio/api/publish/start.html#crafter-studio-api-publish-start

OR you can log in to the database and set the publishing enabled flag in the site table.